# Node.js/JavaScript - Avoid users entering scripts and html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

so bit hard to explain but I will try:
Basically I have chat application running on Node.js
Client side:

```
function sentMessage(){
    if($('#messageInput').val() != "")
    {
    socket.emit('message', $('#messageInput').val());
    addMessage($('#messageInput').val(), "Me", new Date().toISOString(),
     true);
    $('#messageInput').val('');
    }
}
```

so this does two things:
It sends message to server saying there is new message and at same time it adds message to chatwindow (client side).

Server side:

```
socket.on('message', function (message) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', {
        'message' : entities.encode(message),
        'pseudo' : socket['final_user']
    });
db.query('INSERT INTO messages (user_id, message) VALUES (\
"'+socket['final_user']+'", "'+db.escape(message)+'")');    
});
```

So server detects new message, and broadcasts to all users saying there is new message, here it is along with persons name. It also inserts it into database.

So my problem is: if user enters something like  or alert("hello");

it **WORKS** fine for other users, it does not appear and appears as plain code without causing mess, but for the user who entered it - it prints images and alert box.

Also whenever user logs in later, and old messages are loaded using this function:

```
function loadMessages(msg, pseudo, time){
    $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="messagesOLD">' +
    "<span class='msg_date'>"+dateFormat(time)+"</span><span class='msg_seperator'> | </span><span class='msg_name'>"+ pseudo + '</span> : ' + msg + '</div>');
}
```

It also prints alerts and images to user. 
I know many could say just use entities.encode() as I did on server side, but it doesn't work on client side for some reason.

Okay I managed to fix loading previous messages and loading scripts to users because they are being loaded from server side, so I was able to use entities.encode() so now scripts and all possible exploits show up as plain code and are not executed.

However - user who types it still gets the scripts executed.

```
function addMessage(msg, pseudo){
    var post_date = new Date();
    var timesp = post_date;
    if(pseudo == "Me"){
    $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="message msg_owner">' +
    "<span class='msg_date'>"+dateFormat(timesp)+"</span><span class='msg_seperator'> | </span><span class='msg_name'>"+ pseudo + '</span> : ' + msg + '</div>');

    }
    else{
    $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="message">' +
    "<span class='msg_date'>"+dateFormat(timesp)+"</span><span class='msg_seperator'> | </span><span class='msg_name'>"+ pseudo + '</span> : ' + msg + '</div>');
    }
        $('#chatEntries').scrollTop(1E10);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like it's something completely client side then.  What's the contents of the `addMessage` function - this is likely to be where the fault lies

Comment: Why not use `entities.encode()` in the "loadMessages" function too?

Comment: It looks like you're only encoding for entities when it reaches the server - so when added locally it's not going to be encoded.  You may need to review at what point you require it to be encoded.  Personally, I would probably just do it before it's displayed on screen, and keep it as typed during transport/data storage

Comment: If `addMessage` is the same as `loadMessages` and it's using `.append()`, that's what the issue is.  Consider switching to using `.text()` as you'll get the encoding for free, and won't need to worry about it at all.

Comment: I've updated question with addMessage() contents.

Comment: I would just treat self-entered messages just like any other message; have it travel to the server and back before displaying. Doing so will ensure that the messages the user sees are consistent with what others see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation for `append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> Do not use these methods to insert strings obtained from untrusted
>   sources such as URL query parameters, cookies, or form inputs. Doing
>   so can introduce cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. Remove or
>   escape any user input before adding content to the document

Instead, use the [`text` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

```
var newmsg = $('<div class="message msg_owner">' + 
    "<span class='msg_date'>"+dateFormat(timesp)+
    "</span><span class='msg_seperator'> | </span><span class='msg_name'>" +
    pseudo + '</span> : <span class="msg"></span></div>');

//insert the new message using .text, which will encode the message at this point
newmsg.find(".msg").text(msg)

$("#chatEntries").append(newmsg);
```

Note the addition of a `msg` class - if you're already using this elsewhere, you may need to change it.

This *should* negate the need for `entities.encode()` on the server side entirely, but it depends where else these messages are being passed around.

Comment: In theory, if he is properly sanitizing his data on the server (let's hope so) his code should not be vulnerable.

Comment: Which he is for the messages sent to other users, but the local user isn't being sanitised.  Personally I don't like to see things encoded until the point they need to be - it usually results in double encodings etc.  In this case, the point it needs to be encoded is as it's put into the HTML

Comment: You can't sanitize the local user anyway - if he is going to do something malicious to his local code no amount of sanitizing (assuming he leaves that code in place) will accomplish anything, though I understand the issues here, I only commented to make sure people understand that the steps taking here aren't enough BY THEMSELVES to ensure security.

Comment: Here is the result anyway:
http://chaterix.com
email: guest@guest.coma
pass: guests
<br>
It seems to work I think.